# not giving output in c but no compilation error

Tags: c

the program should take n numbers and should return all the numbers in ascending order.
the program compiles with no error.but during runtime gives no output.
i have used array and enter the value in that array. then bubble sort all the elements and arranged them in another array.then printed that array elements in the output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int a[100],c,b,d[100];
    clrscr();
    printf("\n\n enter the number to be arranged\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    for(int i=0; i<=c; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    int max=a[0];
    bg:
    for(i=1; i<c; i++)
    {
        if(max<a[i])
        {
            max=a[i];
        }
        else
        {
            max=a[0];
        }
    }
    d[c-1]=max;
    c=c-1;
    printf("****%d",d[c-1]);
    max=a[0];
    if(c>=0)
    {
        goto bg;
    }
    for(i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        printf("/n%d",d[i]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to indent your code. As it is, it's almost unreadable.

Comment: And don't use `goto` instead of loops, it makes the code even *more* unreadable.

Comment: And while editing your question to at least fix the indentation, then also please tell us the input you give the program.

Comment: Lastly, please [learn how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Also give the output, the desired output and your thinking about what might be wrong. Try to upgrade to a [mcve].

Comment: but goto is conditional here

Comment: Goto is not recommended to use ! In your case i is not declared ! And please put indentation before you post questions in forums like SO ! Please Explain your problem !

Comment: All gotos which replace a loop are conditional.

Comment: Replace `bg:` by `do{` and `if(c>=0)
    {
        goto bg;
    }` by `}while (c>=0);` then go on polishing.

Comment: Delete the first `max=a[0];`, the one inside the loop. It breaks your search for the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the first `max=a[0];`, the one inside the loop.
It breaks your search for the maximum.

The not printing could be explained (see other answer, credits to Artur Pasymowski)), by your input (e.g. from a file) having actually only n inputs, while your input loop is waiting for another one.
If you input manually and give another one it probably works. Then you will notice the sorting problem I pointed out above.

Answer (score 1):

The loop gathering numbers to sort is taking one too many. It should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}
```

After you enter n numbers, it waits for one more, so it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
please define in for loop int 

#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int a[100],c,b,d[100];
    clrscr();
    printf("\n\n enter the number to be arranged\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    for(int i=0; i < c; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    int max=a[0];
    bg:
    for(int i=1; i<c; i++)
    {
        if(max<a[i])
        {
            max=a[i];
        }
        else
        {
            max=a[0];
        }
    }
    d[c-1]=max;
    c=c-1;
    printf("****%d",d[c-1]);
    max=a[0];
    if(c>=0)
    {
        goto bg;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        printf("/n%d",d[i]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: i suggest you to change your array value otherwise static array for ten values or something